# How to re-export overridden MUI theme definitions?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I have a project that has all the MUI theme created, everything is working properly. Now I'd like to extract the defined theme out as a separate library (ex: `@myproject/theme`) such that I could share/redeploy it to various applications, that way, when the theme library gets updated, all downstream apps would inherit all the changes as well.

In most cases, it worked fine, however I am having trouble propagating the overridden `variants` with MUI. For example, I have the following `variants` defined for the `Button`:

```
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
    toolbar: true;
  }
}

export const myThemeOptions = {
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'toolbar' },
          style: { ... }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

export myLightTheme = createTheme(myThemeOptions, 'light'));
```

So the above code used to work just fine within the project (before splitting it out as a lib), and VSCode would be able to see the added `toolbar` variant. However, once the theme is moved to a new project/library (ex: `@myproject/theme` and then let's say I do, `npm install -D @myproject/theme@0.0.1-alpha`), it would no longer recognizing the added `variants`:

[image]

[image]

How can I re-export the definition and then somehow automatically load/overrides the definitions from MUI in the consumer apps? What is the correct way to archive what I am trying to do?

Let me know if I should use a different question title.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all declarations

```
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
    interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
        toolbar: true;
    }
}
```

in the same file there you have theme creation

```
export myLightTheme = createTheme(myThemeOptions, 'light'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your theme doesn't have `.d.ts` file with all overrides/declarations you should add it. And be aware it's (the exact file path) added to your `tsconfig.json` in `compilerOptions` -> `typeRoots` list.